# I have a problem with intel graphics

Tags: 14.04, graphics, video, intel

I use Ubuntu 14.04 to watch movies or animation and see it all as full High Definition(HD).
Since a few days ago I noticed the changing of FPS  and I do not know why. I have chosen installing Intel drivers but the problem still exists?

Anyone knows a solution?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen with other mediaplayers too? VLC, smplayer?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the new kernel and X libraries that shipped as an update to ubuntu 14.04 called called 14.04.2. It was released Feb 20 2015. Although you have to have installed it explicitly: see how here(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

You can read about the update here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2888959/ubuntu-14-04-2-arrives-with-updated-hardware-support-and-a-new-linux-kernel.html

Check if you are running the original 3.13 kernel or the updated 3.16. E.g. run "uname -a" in a terminal.
You can select the kernel upon boot - choose "Advanced ubuntu options" (or something like that).

I don't know if you can do anything about the X update.